# posts/:id/revisions route leaks draft Collectives™ articles

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives, articles

It's now possible for anyone to join a Collective™ and make a draft article. Links to draft articles 404 for those without the proper access, but the `/posts/:id/revisions` route doesn't respect the draft status of an article and displays the revisions list even for drafts. For example, [/posts/71632829/revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71632829/revisions) shows my draft Collective™ article. This route should instead 404 for drafts.

Aside from leaking the contents of article drafts, this could also be abused by spammers to post spam in an essentially unmoderated way: there is no way to flag articles from the revisions page (or from any page for that matter, but hopefully approved and published articles won't be spam), so one could abuse this bug to host spam on SO in a relatively unnoticed way.

Comment: Not sure how it would be used for spam? Our robots.txt file excludes the /posts/ path entirely, so it shouldn't be indexed by any popular search engines. But nonetheless should be investigated.

Comment: @animuson The spam use case I was thinking of is to put spam in draft articles, then to spam links to that draft article page on other sites. I don't know how much spammers use tactics like that though.

Comment: Perhaps more often, now that you've given them the idea. :-) But seriously, that doesn't seem like a big concern, as spammers are not lacking for places to post spam.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know! Nice catch ;). We'll make sure to fix this and will update this post whenever that's done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know! The fix ended up fairly simple and we've solved it today. Please let us know if you still see some irregularities.